# Is each static array member initialized?

Tags: c, c99

From ISO/IEC 9899:1999 -> 6.7.8 Initialization § 10

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
>   then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>   rules.

Did I get this right, that imagine this code:

```
int main()
{
    static char *szArray[4];
    return 0;
}
```

it is ensured that each member of `szArray[]` is initialized with `NULL`?
Or how I can understand "recursively" in this context?

Comment: For practical purposes, on all platforms you are likely to encounter, uninitialized static data is in memory area which is zeroed at program start. The standard is more verbose, because there are (or can be) obscure platforms where it needs to be done differently.

Comment: @hyde Well I'm not developing software for customers I'm developing a server for my self which is compiled and run on freeBSD x86 arch. So I guess there I won'T run in troubble, will I?

Comment: If you assume pointer values are NULL, that is guaranteed by C standard. I just meant, you can also visualize the situation as a zeroed memory area in practice (on any PC or mainstream mobile device).

Comment: Ah ohkay. yeah now I got you. But I was just confused as we know from microsoft that not all what is calling it self c conform, really IS c conform ^^ So i preferred clarifying it, before I'll alter run into trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

`szArray` is an array of 4 elements, each of which is a `char*` pointer. Each of those 4 elements is in initalized to NULL.

What "recursively" means here is that, since data types can be arbitrarily complex (arrays within structures within unions within arrays, etc.), each *member* of an aggregate (array or structure) is initialized following the same rules.

- `szArray` is an aggregate, so "every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules".
- - `szArray[0]` through `szArray[3]` all have pointer type, so each of them "is initialized to a null pointer".

This (probably) does not involve any run-time recursion. On most systems, integer `0`, floating-point `0.0`, and null pointers are all represented as all-bits-zero, so a static aggregate object can *probably* be correctly initialized just by setting it to all-bits-zero. It's the *definition* that's recursive; the initialization of an aggregate object is defined in terms of the initializations of its elements/members, and so on recursively until you get down to individual scalars.

Comment: So if there where a structure of 3 pointers like `struct {int *i;int *j;int *k;}type;`then for an array like `type[3];`each `i`,`j` and `k` would be NULL initalized?

Comment: @Zaibis: Exactly. Objects of arithmetic or pointer type are *scalars*. All object types are either scalars themselves, or are composed (directly or indirectly) of scalars (I'm ignoring `void`, since you can't have an object of type `void` anyway). For any static object with no initializer, each one of the scalars that make it up is initialized to zero or to a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Each member of `szArray` is indeed initialized to `NULL`, *once*, before it is used. In *main* this "once" does not make a difference, but in other functions which may get called many times it is important. It is especially important for thread safe code and re-entrant code, because there is just one value accessed by all calls.

Comment: Exactly thats why I'm working with this currently, as I have to write code that allocates only the first time memory. And has to work threadsafe. But this doesn't matter here. so thanks :) but I have to accept Keith's answer as it is more explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this case you will get an array of four NULL values.

The "recursively" in the spec does not apply to pointers.  It applies to structs.  So for example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Bar {
  int yada;
};

struct Foo {
  struct Bar bar;
  const char* baz;
};

static struct Foo foo;
static struct Foo* foo_ptr;

int main()
{

  printf("foo.bar.yada = %d\n", foo.bar.yada);
  printf("foo_ptr = %p\n", foo_ptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Running the above gives

```
foo.bar.yada = 0
foo_ptr = (nil)
```

The initialization rule has been applied recursively to Foo and then to Bar.  The pointer is simply initialized to zero.

Comment: Are you sure that this is what is mentioned by recursively? As your example isn't really something I would call recursion in any way.

Comment: There are no classes in C99. There are, however, arrays, and the question specifically mentions an array, so you might want to cover that.

Comment: @PascalCuoq thanks for catching my error in referring to C++ when the question was asking about plain C. I removed the reference to class from my answer.  I'll try to come back later and address the question of arrays.

Comment: @Zaibis I added another level of structure containment in the example. You could add an unlimited depth of struct containments in the same way and they would all be initialized by recursive application of the initialization rule.

Comment: Well now i got what you want to mention. But your explenation is pretty weired. But by the way is this a practicable example? i mean wouldn't be the structure Foo be a endless recursion? And how would this be practiced?

Comment: w8 what?! are you sure you dont mean for struct Foo `Bar bar` isntead of `Foo bar`? really conffusing dude...

Comment: @Zaibis you are correct in spotting that typo.  I have now fixed it.  I also has some remaining C++ syntax that I fixed to be plain C. Data structures can only be recursive if they use pointers. This example is not a recursive data structure, but at a meta level the initialization rule is applied recursively.